# function is convex in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u ∈ W^{1,1} (]0, 1[)$ and 
$$J_\varepsilon(u) =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(\varepsilon+x^\alpha)u'^2dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1u^4 dx-\int_0^¹uf dx.$$

Prove $J(u)$ is convex.

My argument is sum of 3 functions.

- The first is quadratic with strictly positive coefficient $\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon+x^\alpha)$, so it is strictly convex.
- The second is also quadratic and equal to $\|u^4\|_{L_4}^4$ so also strictly convex.
- The third is linear so convex.

As a sum of convex and strictly convex functions, $J$ is strictly convex.

Is that a correct proof?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Many thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: I dont think its correct to say that $x^\alpha$ is a coefficient. And the second term is not $\left\|u^{4}\right\|_{L_{4}}^{4}$

Comment: The first term is quadratic in the derivative, so the complete explanation would appeal to the composition of the linear operator (derivative) and the convex one (quadratic). The second one is the summation (integration) of the convex $u^4$.